# PHP select option from database, results not showing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get selected option data from database, my selected option in web can't show anything but an arrow

```
<select>
    <?php
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `User`";
        $result=$database->getData($sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
        <option>
        <?=$row['LastName'].", " .$row['FirstName'];?></option>
    <?php }  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Give the `select` menu a `name` attribute - ie: `name='fred'`

Comment: Выведите `ptint_r($result);` и посмотрите, что Вам приходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u tried var_dump($result)? Is data there? if yes do this inside select.

```
<?php foreach($result as $row) : ?>
<option><?php echo $row['LastName'].", " .$row['FirstName'];?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i tried removing   <?php }  ?>  and it said unexpected end of file

Comment: thanks i already found the problem,  `$result=$database->getData($sql);`    my function called viewData($sql) not getData($sql), thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. I generally find it easier to read the code when I take steps to avoid dropping in and out of php. In your original code, it looks like you have an “=“ before $row[‘LastName’], which doesn’t look right.

```
<select>
<?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `User`";
    $result=$database->getData($sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo “<option>“ . $row['LastName']. ", " .$row['FirstName'] . “</option>”;
    }
?>
</select>
```